# is tg^-1 (x) not the same as tg(x)^-1?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, exponentiation

Well, for better syntax, my question looks like this:

Isn't $tg^{-1}(x)$ the same as $(tg(x))^{-1}$ ?

I always thought that it was absolutely the same.

But I was trying to solve a task on an edx.org website and I don't understand why their answer is different. Here is the [image with the task](https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/2/AACwcJiIcRBkc8tbmEYpnFSubJmhaKe99TPXJP4i8DPqvA/12/55240438/png/32x32/3/1450803600/0/2/trigonometry_task.png/EISG0ioY6OkJIAIoAg/pckHYV9pe5G7PtbngH4Q5de-WHJw6sO-U_6ecQOoXJA?size_mode=3&size=1600x1200) (and their solution)

In short, it asks what possible values can the following expression have:

$$tg^{-1}(sin(n*\pi)),$$
where `n` is an integer.

To me it was obvious that $sin(\pi*n)$ is zero, and $tg(0)$ is therefore also zero, and $tg^{-1}(0) \equiv 1/tg(0)$ should be $infinity$.

But in their answer it is said that $tan^{-1}$ function is defined between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ and "therefore" the answer can only be zero.

Is there something I don't know or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: it is not the same $\tan^{-1}(x)$ means the inverse function of $\tan(x)$ namely $\arctan(x)$

Comment: what the hell :) but $sin^2(x)$ *is* the same as $(sin(x))^2$!

Comment: you areusing MathJax. So, it could be better if you write $\arctan$ instead of $tg^{-1}$.

Comment: It's true that $\sin^{2}x = (\sin x)^{2}$ by convention, but also by convention $\sin^{-1} x \neq (\sin x)^{-1}$; the left-hand side refers to $\arcsin x$, the right to $\csc x$. (Similarly, if your question had meant the reciprocal of $\tan$, it would most likely have read $\cot$.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\tan^{-1}$ is sometimes used to denote the arctangent function $\arctan$. That is,

$$\tan^{-1}(x) = \arctan(x) = y \Leftrightarrow \tan(y)=x.$$

Comment: Alright, thanks! Now it makes sense. But i find that extremely confusing. Like I said in the previous comment, $sin^2(x)$ *is* the same as $(sin(x))^2$, so the notation is not consistent. And I wonder why I have never heard about it before. I guess I just somehow chose to ignore it.

Comment: I agree, it is a confusing notation. Nevertheless, in what I have seen, when applied directly to the function, it is more common the use of $f^{-1}$ to denote the inverse function rather than $1/f$. For positive exponents, I've seen both cases.

Answer (score 3):

The notation
$$f^{-1}$$
can either mean the inverse of $f$ (when the inverse is defined, sometimes the inverse of a restriction of $f$ to a smaller domain where it is injective), or the point-wise reciprocal of $f$ (when $f$ takes values in a field like $\mathbb{R}$).

The first $f^{-1}$ is with respect to function composition $\circ$, and we have:
$$(f^{-1}\circ f) = \mathrm{id} \quad\text{ and } \quad(f\circ f^{-1}) = \mathrm{id}$$
where $\mathrm{id}$ is the identity map. In other words $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ for all $x$ and $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$ for all $y$.

The second $f^{-1}$ is sometimes written $1/f$, and is with respect to pointwise multiplication, we have for each $x$:
$$(f(x))(f^{-1}(x))=1$$
where $1$ is the number one in the codomain of $f$.

---

Actually, the same is true for other superscripts (exponents), for example:
$$f^3$$
might mean the function
$$(f\circ f\circ f)(x) = f(f(f(x)))$$
or the function
$$(f\cdot f\cdot f)(x) = (f(x))(f(x))(f(x))$$

For trigonometric functions these confusions are particularly common since many writers use e.g. $\cos^2$ for the point-wise square, and at the same time use $\cos^{-1}$ for the inverse (also known as arcus cosine, arccos).

---

See [Wikipedia: Inverse trigonometric functions § Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Notation) for a discussion of notations used and their problems.

Comment: By the way, $\arctan$ is *not* the inverse function of $\tan$ (which is not invertible), but the inverse of the restriction of $\tan$ to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Using $\tan^{-1}$, besides being confusing, is an abuse. The same holds for $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ versus $\sin^{-1}$ and $\cos^{-1}$. Alas, abuse of notation is quite common in mathematics.

Comment: @egreg I absolutely agree. That is why I said _sometimes the inverse of a restriction of $f$ to a smaller domain where it is injective_ in a parenthesis. It is abuse, but common, so often the abuse "works".